# How do I determine battery manufacturers/companies whose batteries that have met UL 1642 certification?

Tags: batteries, certification, ul

How do I determine battery manufacturers/companies whose batteries that have met UL 1642 certification?

I am asking because I want to determine other companies whose products have successfully passed the UL1642 standard.

I look forward and appreciate your help.

Comment: Have you tried any ways to find out UL 1642 certification so far? Such as checking the company web site...? Also, it's not clear to me what you mean by "I want to determine other companies whose products have successfully passed the UL1642 standard"

Answer (score 0):

If the item claims certification to a UL standard they should have a UL listed file number printed on the item, (or a number from another accredited test lab, for e.g. ETL, CSA, that actually did the certification) .  If the item cannot include printing, such as very small items, then there might be separate literature with the certification information.  These file numbers can be searched on the UL web site, (or other testing lab sites).

Manufacturers sometimes post their certificates on there own web site, but to be sure always verify they are listed directly on the legitimate test lab site.

Here is the page for UL: 
https://www.ul.com/database

Here is a pdf guide to searching UL: https://fcia.org/articles/ULQuickGuide.pdf